# gulp-responsive проблемы с обработкой svg

Tags: javascript, gulp

Использую модуль gulp-responsive для изменения изображений, имею ошибку:
Код:

> [15:41:15] Error in plugin "gulp-responsive"
>   Message:
>       File `footer\facebook.svg`: Unsupported output format unsupported
>   Details:
>       domainEmitter: [object Object]
>       domain: [object Object]
>       domainThrown: false
>   Цитата

мой код обработки изображений

```
gulp.task("images", () => {
return gulp.src(paths.images.src)
    .pipe(imagemin([
        imagemin.svgo({
            plugins: [
                { removeViewBox: false },
                { removeUnusedNS: false },
                { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false },
                { cleanupIDs: false },
                { removeComments: true },
                { removeEmptyAttrs: true },
                { removeEmptyText: true },
                { collapseGroups: true }
            ]
        })
    ]))
    .pipe(responsive({
            'footer/*.svg':{},
             '**/logo*.png': [
                {
                    width: "100%",
                    quality: 100
                },{
                    width: 50,
                    quality: 75,
                    rename: {
                        suffix: '-50w',
                        extname: '.png'
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: 25,
                    quality: 50,
                    rename: {
                        suffix: '-25w',
                        extname: '.png'
                    }
                }
            ],       
        {
            errorOnUnusedConfig: false,
            errorOnUnusedImage: false,
            errorOnEnlargement: false,
            quality: 80,
            progressive: false,
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dist))
    .on("end", browsersync.reload);
```

});
Задача в том, по сути, чтобы при сборке проекта svg файлы то же переносились, а не пропускались. как это сделать? спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-responsive

> gulp-responsive depends on sharp. Sharp is one of the fastest Node.js modules for resizing JPEG, PNG, WebP and TIFF images.

То есть, только эти растровые форматы. SVG не поддерживается.

Просто для копирования файлов я обычно использую gulp-newer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer

Answer (score 0):

responsive не даст пропустить через себя svg как уже сказал Scriptach.
Я использую вот такую конструкцию, думаю вы найдете в ней решение своей проблемы

```js
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    newer        = require('gulp-newer'),
    rename       = require('gulp-rename'),
    imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    responsive   = require('gulp-responsive'),
    merge        = require('merge-stream');

// 'img/_src/.icon/' folder only for favicon
gulp.task('img-processing', function() {
    var iconFold = gulp.src('app/img/_src/.icon/**/*.{svg,png,ico}')
    .pipe(newer('app/img/@icon'))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img/@icon'));

    var specFold = gulp.src(['app/img/_src/**/*.{svg,gif}', '!app/img/_src/.icon'])
    .pipe(newer('app/img/@spec'))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img/@spec'));

    var mainFold = gulp.src(['app/img/_src/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}', '!app/img/_src/.icon'])
    .pipe(newer('app/img/@1x'))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(responsive({
        '*': [{
            // Produce @2x images
            width: '100%', quality: 90, rename: { prefix: '@2x/', },
        }, {
            // Produce @1x images
            width: '50%', quality: 90, rename: { prefix: '@1x/', }
        }]
    })).on('error', function () { console.log('No matching images found') })
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {path.extname = path.extname.replace('jpeg', 'jpg')}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/img'));

    return merge(iconFold, specFold, mainFold);
});
```